# findOrNew returns an array instead of object when condition is not on id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have 2 tables `users` and `user_meta`

in my `users` model i have

```
function meta() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\userMeta');
}
```

in my controller when i want to save user and user meta

```
function store( Request $request , $id = 0 ) {    
    $user = User::findOrNew($id);
    $user->save() ;

    $meta = UserMeta::findOrNew(['user_id'=>$id]);
    $user->meta()->save($meta);    
}
```

when im trying to save meta i get  this error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save()  must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model,

here is the problem `UserMeta::findOrNew(['user_id'=>$id])` returns an array instead of object ... which is weird .. while `User::findOrNew($id)` itself returns and object ....  i'm guessing it's becuz of my conditions (its the only difference between 2 query)

right now i have to do something like this

```
$meta = UserMeta::findOrNew(['user_id'=>$id]);
if(is_array($meta)) {
    $user->meta()->save($meta[0]);
} else {
    $user->meta()->save($meta);
}
```

which i dont like and looks wrong !

Comment: Perhaps `UserMeta` has multiple row with same `user_id`

Comment: @jonju no it's a 1to1 relation so database will not accept same user_id more than once

Comment: But this doesn't  `HasOneOrMany` look One to One relation.

Comment: can you show the output of `print_r($meta->toArray());`

Comment: @jonju sorry i dont understand what you're saying , but as i defined in the model , users and user_meta have 1 to 1 relation ... also i've looked in the database i only have 1 user and 1 meta

Comment: I mean write this line `print_r($meta->toArray());` just below this line `$meta = UserMeta::findOrNew(['user_id'=>$id]);` and you should be able to see an array. Can I see that array?

Comment: @jonju i did understand that :) i didn't undrestant what u said in the comment before `But this doesn't HasOneOrMany look One to One relation`

Comment: @jonju i get an empty array `Array ( ) ` when there is nothing in database

Comment: That explains it!! I hope you've overcome your problem with @Ghitu Illie-Alin's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function findOrNew() is probably not what your are looking for.
It is intended to be used as follows:

```
// the array in the second parameter specifies which columns are 
// included in the resulting model (if found)
// it is NOT used as a WHERE clause
$meta = UserMeta::findOrNew($id, ['user_id'=>$id]);
```

What you are looking for:

```
// adds where clause (returns new model if it does not exist)
$meta = UserMeta::firstOrNew(['user_id' => $id]);

// same as above but persists new model to database
$meta = UserMeta::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $id]);
```

**Reason why firstOrNew() returns no single model in your case:**

This is the implementation of findOrNew Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php :

```
public function findOrNew($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (! is_null($model = $this->find($id, $columns))) {
        return $model;
    }

    return $this->model->newInstance();
}
```

As you can see, the first parameter is not intended for the columns.

If you have a look at the find method in **$this->find($id, $columns)**
you will see:

```
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id)) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    $this->query->where($this->model->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $id);

    return $this->first($columns);
}
```

As your passed an array as $id the result of $this->findMany() is returned, which is a Collection.

Comment: i see , so we cant change WHERE clause in the findOrNew  ?

Comment: exactly it only searches by id(s)  or whatever you have defined as primary key column name

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use FirstOrCreate instead of findOrNew.

Comment: thanx , that would be plan B

Comment: `findOrNew`  is behaving differently at the same time. And according to OP it's one to one relation. It should work as it did in case of the `user`